# How can get snapshot of my data from firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to displaying videos . For that I saving data to firebase . And when user clicking on a video I wanna displaying the videos in my fullscreen method .The saving into firebase is already done. Now im trying to give my page some data where I displaying the video .
Im doing like this .

```
class VideoPage2new extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = '/Video2';
  final String id ;

  const VideoPage2new({Key key, this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPage2newState createState() => _VideoPage2newState();
}

class _VideoPage2newState extends State<VideoPage2new> {
  Stream mystreamofallvideos;
    mystreamofallvideos =    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').doc(widget.id).snapshots()
---- -- - - -

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: mystreamofallvideos,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  controller:
                      PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 1),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot videos = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                    return Stack(
                      
                      children: [
                      Videoplayeritem(videos.data()['videourl']),
                - -- -
```

And this is where im calling this page

```
  Future myVideos;

getalldata() async {
   String myID= FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    myVideos = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: myID)
        .get();

 FutureBuilder(
                       future: myVideos,
                        builder: ( context, snapshot) {
                       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                 return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                  }
                                   if(videos>0){
                           return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              DocumentSnapshot video =
                             snapshot.data.docs[index];
                              return InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                 
                                   print(video.data()['videourl']);
                                  return VideoPage2new(
                                 id: video.data()['videourl'],
```

So on the on tap function I wanna giving the Videopage2 the current video. I print in the onTap function adnd it it is equal to my firebase object.But it dont looks like Videoplayeritem getting the correct data
This is how it look in firebase [image]

Comment: try: `id: video.data()['id'],`. I'm not sure why you are using `['videourl']`, I can't see it in firebase.

Comment: In video url is the same value actually . its not working

Comment: I changed video 0 to the  id of the video maybe I should call this video with the id of it and not the id property ? iF so how I can call it ?. I tried it in mystreamofallvideos variable if you watch my post